# Как сделать автоматическую подгрузку вариантов выбора в поисковое окно?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Есть окно для набора города. Как сделать,чтобы при наборе букв города автоматически через ajax подгружались города из бд на эти буквы и выпадал список этих городов в блоке variants как в поиске google?

```
<input id="city" name="city">
<div class="variants"></div>
```

Js

```
$('input').on('input', function(e) {
   /*что здесь делать*/
});
```

Php

```
function city(Request $request) {
  $abc=  $request->input('city');
  $allcities=DB::table('city')->all();
  //что дальше
}
```

Comment: [Отправлять запрос](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) пробовали?

Comment: А сколько городов в базе? Если до 10000 я бы все сразу выгружал на страницу, если сотни тысяч то через обращение к среверу.

Comment: Города РФ только

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete - посоветую использовать готовое решение, не вижу смысла в данном случае делать новые велосипеды.